# Quando chamar o saveChanges() no EF quando preciso de um ID identity para finalizar a função?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, framework

Estou desenvolvendo uma função utilizando c# e entity framework que é o método Create de uma atividade.

Meu problema é que nesse mesmo save, preciso inserir dados em duas tabelas: Atividades e subatividades, onde a tabela de subatividades possui uma foreign key apontando para o ID da atividade. O que ocorre é que quando eu chamo o saveChanges(), retorna um erro, por conta da atividade ainda não ter um id (é auto-incremento) e com isso a subatividade fica com a foreign key nula, causando o erro

Exemplo:

```
_db.activity.Add(actv);

foreach (var item in actv.subActivities)
{
    var SubActivities= new SubActivities();
    SubActivities.activityId= actv.Id;
    SubActivities.PassengerId = item.PassengerId;
    SubActivities.FunctionId = item.FunctionId;
    _db.SubActivities.AddRange(SubActivities);
}

_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: adiciona todas as `SubActivities` dentro de uma icollection na activity e faz o add apenas na activity. o EF vai fazer os inserts em cascata.

Comment: Falta contexto mas se há relacionamento, não precisa de um for pra recriar aquilo que já está pronto. Só gravar a partir disso